# passing the datagrid row value to the next form label

Tags: c#

hi i am working on winform and i have a datadrid view, i have a context menu strip. on that edit is written. when i click on datadrid, right click a context menu is open with edit. when clicked it should pass the value to a new form, i have written the code for transfer but it is not passing i dont know whats the problem here

```
       private void editToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form6 f = new Form6();
     f.label1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

    }
```

is the code correct?

Comment: You also need to open the form. Where is the code for that ? f.ShowDialog(); ?

Comment: opps that was the silly mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Form6 is not already opened then you will need to show it after assigning text to its label.

```
private void editToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form6 f = new Form6();
    f.label1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    f.Show();

}
```

If Form6 is already opened, you need to use the instance of Form6 and not to create new instance, you can use [Application.OpenForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eh13dca9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to get already opened forms.

```
Form6 f = (Form6)Application.OpenForms["form6"];
f.label1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: adil bhai. it is neccesary form should be open?
i cant create new instance and pass it to the label?

Comment: Based on what do you say it should be an open form? OP clearly said he needs it on a new form.

Comment: No, but you will need to show that form after assigning value to it.

Comment: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
this error is coming sir.

Comment: @shariq Either you have 0 selected rows, or you have 0 cells in the row.

Comment: sir @ rotem the problem is. the context menu strip, i have a context menustrip. i want that when it is clicked clicked it should pass the value  of the selected row and column1 of that row to the new form's label. can i do that?

Comment: @shariq_khan if you are getting null with Application.OpenForms["form6"]; then make sure your object of Form6 is named form6 or pass the name object for Form6 you have and it should be opened. I have updated my answer if you do already opened the form6 as in your question, you need to show it.

Comment: You need to debug it to see where you are getting null, check if dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count is 1 or greate, You may not have any selected row.